# Laravel Query Exception Error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to run the following "Results()" query and getting the following error related to a foreach loop in my view:

```
public function index()
    {

        //show view of homepage
        return View::make('index');
    }

    public function results()
    {   
        $query = DB::table('Unions'); // Get the table before applying the where clauses

        if (Request::get('Affilation')) {
            $Affilation = Input::get('Affilation');
            if ($Affilation != null) {
                $query = $query->where('Affilation', $Affilation);
            }
        }

        if (Request::get('Office_State')) {
            $Office_State = Input::get('Office_State');
            if ($Office_State != null) {
                $query = $query->where('Office_State', $Office_State);
            }
        }

        if (Request::has('Local_Name')) {
            $Local_Name = Input::get('Local_Name');
            if ($Local_Name != null) {
                $query = $query->where('Local_Name', $Local_Name);
            }
        }

        $results = $query->get(); // Calling get() will execute the query, so it must be last to be called
        //show results from union search
        return View::make('results')->with('union', $results);
     } 



    public function profile($Local_Name)
    {

            $union = Union::whereLocal_name($Local_Name)->first();

        //show individual union profile
        return View::make('profile', ['union' => $union]);
        }
```

This is a large chuck of the error:

> [2015-02-28 15:21:48] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException'
>   with message 'Undefined variable: unions' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\views\828b81503d4e5a41a8d04770b175c57d:44

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\views\828b81503d4e5a41a8d04770b175c57d(44): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 44, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(9876): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(9754): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(9741): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(9732): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(10434): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(9964): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
```

And this is the view line 44 being referenced:

```
<?php if($unions->count()): ?>
        <?php foreach($unions as $union): ?>
```

Comment: You pass `union` to the view and try to access it with `unions`.

Comment: @lukasgeiter are you saying that my foreach loop is incorrect? This query was working before when it was very simple like this: public function results()
    {

  $query = Request::get('Affilation');
  

  $unions = $query 
   ? Union::where('Affilation', 'LIKE', "$query")->get()
   : Union::all();

  //show results from union search
  return View::make('results')->withUnions($unions); 

     }

Comment: No I'm saying the problem is the variable name. `return View::make('results')->with('union', $results);` and `foreach($unions as $union)`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a view with:

```
union
```

And you are trying to foreach

```
unions
```

Try `return View::make('results')->with('unions', $results);`

Comment: After that change my laravel.log is still pointing to that line 44, only it's saying something different: [2015-02-28 16:42:32] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function count() on a non-object' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\views\828b81503d4e5a41a8d04770b175c57d:44
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []

Comment: Thanks to both you guys. That fixed the error. As for the resulting error after, I removed ->Count(). I'm still not getting a response from my db for its a start. Hope this helps someone else.